# how can I interpret some html that I get from a database in a view?

Tags: php

Coming from a field of a database I get a result that looks like this

[image]

I require that this result is interpreted as html in a view, for this I use the function `html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` that achieves the next output.

[image]

At this point I hope that the content is displayed as HTML but it does not happen that way, could you please guide me what is the correct way to achieve this.

I'm dealing with this, which at first seemed like a simple matter. and probably it is. I think it's probably that I'm missing something. In any case, I welcome any comments

Thanks in advance

I got the solution to this problem thanks to a series of filters, I describe the solution below, I hope it will be useful to someone

```
$html = html_entity_decode($value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$html = stripslashes($html);
$html = str_replace('rn', '<br>', $html);
$html = html_entity_decode($html);

echo $html;
```

This is the final output

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the output is JSON? Because slashes are escaped `\/\/`.

Comment: Instead of str_replace you should use `nl2br();`.

Comment: In fact DanFromGermany it is correct that the data comes from json, specifically from a field of type longtext that stores data in json format and from which I extracted the data using json functions in mariadb, for this field I made a query that looks like this `...JSON_VALUE(params, '$.customfield') CV...`

Comment: lol :-) Then you can just do `json_decode()` without you having to do all this parsing stuff.

Comment: I have not checked yet, although if it is indeed the most friendly solution would have been timely in response to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your data most likely is JSON, you can see it because the normal slash `/` is escaped `\/`, which is required in JSON notation.

So it is much better to simply use `json_decode()` instead of parsing the data yourself.

Try this instead:

```
$html = json_decode($value);
```